# How to Schedule backups in SQL Azure

Tags: azure, backup, azure-sql-database

How can I schedule backups for my SQL Azure DBs. I suspect I need to schedule:

1) Create Database [DBCopy] as copy of [DBlive]
2) Export [DBCopy] to Azure Storage.

The frequency would likely be once a day.

I cannot find an Azure Scheduler to help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql-bi-sap-cloud-crm_all_in_one_place/archive/2013/07/24/sql-azure-automated-database-export.aspx ?

Under the hood it does the exact same steps.

Comment: Thank you for this. Most useful. Out of interest what frequency and retention ratio do you use?

Comment: I am thinking about 1 day/3 day.

Comment: Well, I think it depends on your customer needs vs costs (daily backup will double your DB costs). However in my case, once a day was not enough. I'm using Jenkins installed on Azure VM for scheduling 3 backups a day and backing up blob storage.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to schedule database backups in sql Azure. This is taken care by the service. You have Point in time restore and Geo restore features in Azure.

Comment: where do you access the point in time restore features? My 6 months in production Azure database doesn't have any restore options and shows no available LTR backups.